# Can Flink run multiple streams based off initial patterns?

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I'm trying to understand if Flink can perform the way I need it to.

Using the CEP library for pattern matching, is it possible to set up multiple streams based off initial pattern match?

For instance, a message comes in and matches pattern x1, and then the next message matches pattern y1, the following is y2, and the next is x2.
Is there a way for Flink to distinguish between the multiple sets of patterns, and keep looking for each pattern match over a specified length of time?

Or does Flink just ignore messages that don't match the next part of the pattern? If the order is x1 > y1 > y2 > x2, will it just ignore y1 and y2 because they don't match the pattern of x1?

Comment: Could you explain a little more what do you mean? Possibly with some code examples for the `Patterns`?

Comment: Well, I basically need multiple files with different stream patterns.
I'm using Scala right now, but I will probably use Java. I'm still trying to figure out how this works, but I wanted to see if anyone knew offhand before I get too deep into this.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz
For example: 
`val start : Pattern[Event, _] = Pattern.begin("start")
start.where(event => ... /* some condition */)
patternState.within(Time.seconds(10))`
Where pattern starts, if an event comes in that doesn't match/continue the first pattern, is it possible to use a different pattern?

Comment: You can apply as many patterns as you like to a stream, they will be independent then. I mean then a single event could match to multiple patterns. I hope for 1.3.0 we will be able to introduce `optional` quantifier, so you could then specify that the first part is optional and will try to match on the second part of Pattern.

Comment: You mean matching over sections of a single pattern? or matching over two different patterns?
Sorry I'm so confusing, I'm still brand new to this.